# PowerApps - Display Image received by custom connector via ASP.NET API

Tags: asp.net, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, powerapps

I‘m using an Azure hosted ASP.NET API to deliver items from my backend to a PowerApps canvas app. Some items have images assigned to them. In those cases I supply the image ID, to download the image on demand with a GetImage(id) method. In this method I return the content in the HTTPResponse. This works so far. I can call the method from a browser and the image is being displayed. On a mobile device I can not use the URL directly, because the connection is secured by Azure AD. I need to receive the image using the method result of my custom connector. Unfortunately I cannot find a way to populate the image control with string containing the raw image data. How can that to be done?
I could return any other type in the API, if that solves the problem.

Regards

Sven

Comment: Have you tried using the Azure Blob Storage connector? https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/upload-files-from-powerapps-using-the-azure-blob-storage-connector/

Comment: Unfortunately that does not help, as my imagesare delivered from the backend ERP. Storing them in Azure is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can return an image directly from the custom connector to the app. In the response of the custom API you'll need to define the format as binary and media kind as image.

```
        "responses": {
          "default": {
            "description": "default",
            "schema": {
              "type": "string",
              "format": "binary",
              "x-ms-media-kind": "image"
            }
          }
        },
```

For example, this is one Azure Function that have that returns a barcode, given a code (not production-ready, more a proof-of-concept):

```
#r "System.Drawing"

using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using ZXing;
using ZXing.Common;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{

    // parse query parameter
    string code = GetQueryStringValue(req, "code");
    string widthStr = GetQueryStringValue(req, "width") ?? "100";
    string heightStr = GetQueryStringValue(req, "height") ?? "50";

    var width = int.Parse(widthStr);
    var height = int.Parse(heightStr);

    if (code == null)
    {
        // Get request body
        dynamic body = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
        code = body?.code;
    } 

    if (code == null)
    {
        return req.CreateResponse(
            HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
            "Please pass a code on the query string or in the request body");
    }

    var writer = new BarcodeWriterPixelData
    {
        Format = BarcodeFormat.UPC_A,
        Options = new EncodingOptions { Height = height, Width = width }
    };

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
    {
        code = "123456789012";
    }

    var pixelData = writer.Write(code);
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    var bitmap = pixelData.ToBitmap();
    bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
    ms.Position = 0;

    var content = new StreamContent(ms);
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = content };
}

private static string GetQueryStringValue(HttpRequestMessage req, string name)
{
    return req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
        .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, name, true) == 0)
        .Value;
}
```

It uses the ZXing NuGet package that needs to be declared in Project.json:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "ZXing.Net": "0.16.4"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

Then you define the type of the

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "BarcodeGenerator",
    "description": "Barcode generator",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "host": "YOUR_FUNCTION_APP_NAME_HERE.azurewebsites.net",
  "basePath": "/api/",
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "consumes": [],
  "produces": [],
  "paths": {
    "/BarcodeGenerator": {
      "get": {
        "responses": {
          "default": {
            "description": "default",
            "schema": {
              "type": "string",
              "format": "binary",
              "x-ms-media-kind": "image"
            }
          }
        },
        "summary": "Generate barcode",
        "description": "Generate a barcode.",
        "operationId": "GenerateBarcode",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "code",
            "in": "query",
            "required": true,
            "type": "integer"
          },
          {
            "name": "width",
            "in": "query",
            "required": false,
            "type": "integer"
          },
          {
            "name": "height",
            "in": "query",
            "required": false,
            "type": "integer"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {},
  "parameters": {},
  "responses": {},
  "securityDefinitions": {},
  "security": [],
  "tags": []
}
```

Hope this helps!